# Can not use React-Native-Orientation

Tags: react-native, android-orientation

After installing the module:  react-native-orientation
and running my app I am getting:

*Native module Orientation tried to override OrientationModule. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true. This error may also be present if the package is present only once in getPackages() but is also automatically added later during build time by autolinking. Try removing the existing entry and rebuild*

I am using

"dependencies": {
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
"react-native-sensors": "^7.2.0",
"rxjs": "^6.6.6"
}

Any ideas why this error is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: did you use manual linking after install package?

Comment: nope... I only used  "npm install --save react-native-orientation" as typically is done with all React native apps